# Does office365 require certificate renewal

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, microsoft-office-365

We are using Office365 for our mail in a hybrid setup so we have an exchange server with the transport role installed but all mailboxes are hosted on the Microsoft cloud. 
I was wondering if you need to renew your certificate for web mail access?

I have only ever been involved with hosted exchange on site and I know you need a cert for webmail.
I contacted our re-seller and they said the cert gets auto-renewed.
I'm not totally sure this is correct and obviously I don't want us to have any downtime because of this. Would anyone have experience with Certificates and Office365

Comment: Are you using the outlook.com domain for webmail or your own domain?

Answer (score 1):

All of the Office 365 Exchange CAS and Transport certificates are handled by Microsoft. Most of the servers are *.outlook.com anyway so they are out of your hands.